# How can I find integers $n \gt 1$ such that the average of $1^2,2^2,3^2...n^2$ is itself a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

> $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

so we would like to solve

> $6k^2=(n+1)(2n+1)$

here we see that $6|(n+1)(2n+1)\implies 2|n+1$

hence we can set $n=2j-1$

$2j(4j-1)=6k^2\implies j(4j-1)=3k^2$

how can  i find $j$ ,beside trial-and-error

$n=1$ is trivial

Comment: Note: $n=1$ is the answer to the question in the title - are you asking for more values than this?

Comment: yes $n=1$ is a special case,so we want to know if there is other possibilities

Comment: I've changed the title accordingly.

Comment: yes ,the updated title is perfect,i will have to use that etiquette from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are looking for $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}i^2=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$. Set $n_0=n+1$.

The equation becomes $n_0(2n_0-1)=6k^2$. So $n_0$ is even.

Set $n_0=2n_1$ to get $n_1(4n_1-1)=3k^2$. Now suppose $3|n_1$ and set $n_1=3n_2$. Then $n_2(12n_2-1)=k^2$. Since $n_2$ and $12n_2-1$ are coprime, both have to be squares. But $12n_2-1$ is never a square because $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $4$.

Hence we must have $3\nmid n_1$. But then $3|4n_1-1$, so $n_1\equiv 1\mod{3}$. Set $n_1=3m+1$.

The equation is now $(3m+1)(4m+1)=k^2$. Since $3m+1$ and $4m+1$ are coprime, $3m+1=k_1^2$ and $4m+1=k_2^2$.

Now just go through the first few squares to find some solutions. The smallest solution is $k_1=13$, $k_2=15$, $m=56$ which gives $n=337$.

Comment: Well your approach actually uses Pell's equation in a subtle way.To solve $3m+1=k_1^2,4m+1=k_2^2$ we need the Pell's equation $4k_1^2-3k_2^2=1$ which is more complicated to solve and you reach to it after some calculations. So do not mislead saying things like "an approach without Pell's equation" actually your solution is way longer where we can actually get the required Pell's equation just from the first condition as mentioned in my post.Anyhoo Peace.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I just found out that Pell's equation exists 34 minutes ago. Also, I'm not the one who accepted this answer, its the OP, I would gladly delete it, but one cannot delete accepted answers. @Joybangla, ps. Thank you very much for the downvote.

Comment: The next solution to $ 2 n^2 + 3 n + 1 = 6 k^2  $ after $(n,k)$ is
$ (97n+168k+72, 56n+97k + 42).  $

Comment: @Jonas12: Please unaccept this answer and accept one of the others. Any of them is better.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, but it leads to one.  You would presumably convert the equation $j(4j-1) = 3k^2$ into a Pell equation by multiplying both sides by $16$ and obtaining $(8j-1)^2 - 3(4k)^2 = 1$.  The actual minimum such value of $n$ is $337$.

Comment: The next solution to $ 2 n^2 + 3 n + 1 = 6 k^2  $ after $(n,k)$ is
$ (97n+168k+72, 56n+97k + 42).  $

Answer (score 1):

This is an IMO Shortlist but I am having trouble remembering the source.Anyway the solution is somewhat like this 
$(n+1)(2n+1)=6m^2\implies (4n+3)^2-48m^2=1$ now it remains to solve the Pell equation. Which is trivial since we have the seed solution $(m,n)=(1,1)$ hence there are infinitely many.Now to find them explicitly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation and remember only the solutions which are of the form $4n+3$ are elligible so we might have to remove some solutions. I will leave that up to you after generating some solutions it clearly shows

Comment: it also appeared on this british olympiad http://www.bmoc.maths.org/home/bmolot.pdf
 page 4

Comment: i will try the Pell's equation,this is perfect,exactly what i wanted

Comment: The next solution to $ 2 n^2 + 3 n + 1 = 6 k^2  $ after $(n,k)$ is
$ (97n+168k+72, 56n+97k + 42).  $ Beginning with $(1,1).$

Answer (score 1):

Once you have something in the form $p^2-3q^2=1$ (you have $7^2-3\cdot 4^2=1$ if you work through the arithmetic, so $p=7, q=4$) you can do the following trick.

$$(p+q\sqrt 3)(p-q\sqrt 3)=1$$ now raise it to the power $n$ giving $$(p+q\sqrt 3)^n(p-q\sqrt 3)^n=1$$

So with $n=2$ you get $(p^2+3q^2+2pq\sqrt 3)(p^2+3q^2-2pq\sqrt 3)=1$ or $$(p^2+3q^2)^2-3(2pq)^2=1$$

Also if $(p,q)$ and $(r,s)$ are solutions, you get another one from $$(p+q\sqrt 3)(r+s\sqrt 3)$$ This doesn't generate any new ones if you are doing powers of a single solution - but it can give a recurrence for the coefficients of the powers, which can aid computation. It is worth checking through some of these relationships (they are also linked in to continued fractions).

Answer (score 0):

The next solution to $$ 2 n^2 + 3 n + 1 = 6 k^2  $$ after $(n,k)$ is
$$ (97n+168k+72, 56n+97k + 42).  $$ Beginning with $(1,1)$ we see
$$ (1,1),  $$
$$ (337,195),  $$
$$ (65521,37829),  $$
$$ (12710881,7338631),  $$
$$ (2465845537, 1423656585),  $$

I wondered if anything new showed up by going backwards. This would be possible because it is not a pure Pell equation, it is adjusted with constant terms. However, nothing new:

The previous solution to $$ 2 n^2 + 3 n + 1 = 6 k^2  $$ before $(n,k)$ is
$$ (97n-168k+72, -56n+97k - 42).  $$ Beginning with $(1,1)$ we see
$$ (1,1),  $$
$$ (1,-1),  $$
$$ (337,-195),  $$
$$ (65521,-37829),  $$
$$ (12710881,-7338631),  $$
$$ (2465845537, -1423656585),  $$